# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I am trying to run my docker image, but I am receiving the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"python3\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    python3 python3-dev gcc \
    gfortran musl-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache libressl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev

RUN python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apk --no-cache add git

RUN apk add mariadb-dev

WORKDIR /socialworks-api

COPY . /socialworks-api

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

ENV PATH="/opt/gtk/bin:$env/development.env"

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

I think the issue might be with the ENV PATH which I set. I have also tried setting it to:

```
ENV PATH="/opt/gtk/bin:${env/development.env}"
```

But I would receive the following error when building my dockerfile:

```
Step 11/14 : ENV PATH="/opt/gtk/bin:${env/development.env}"
failed to process "\"/opt/gtk/bin:${env/development.env}\"": missing ':' in substitution
```

Without setting the environment, my application won't run.

I have also tried running on my dockerfile this command:

```
RUN export $(grep -v '^#' ./env/development.env | xargs)
```

It build successfully, but when I enter this command to the terminal:

docker run -it flaskapp

I am receiving an error that it still unable to locate the env variables.

```
$ docker run -it flaskapp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
    app.config.from_object("config.Config")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/config.py", line 174, in from_object
    obj = import_string(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 568, in import_string
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/socialworks-api/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Config(object):
  File "/socialworks-api/config.py", line 5, in Config
    MYSQL_HOST = os.environ['MYSQL_HOST']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'
```

Comment: Yes, your `$PATH` setting removes all of the system directories like `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.  Make sure to include the existing `$PATH` in the variable value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please specify what command should I run in my dockerfile? Because my full environment path is socialworks-api/env/development.env and my workdir is socialworks-api, I think it should be enough for env/development.env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you specify

```
ENV PATH="/opt/gtk/bin:$env/development.env"
```

When you later run `python3`, the system looks in *only* these two directories, and when there's not a Python there, you get the error you see.  It's probably in `/usr/bin/python3`, but the directory `/usr/bin` isn't in `$PATH`.

The simplest answer here is to delete this line entirely.  Your Dockerfile creates neither a `/opt/gtk` nor a `/development.env` directory, so there's no files in either path that could be executed.  If you do need to install custom software, putting it in a directory that's in the default system path (like `/usr/local/bin`) is a good approach.

If you do need to keep this line, make sure the existing `$PATH` stays as part of the value.

```
ENV PATH="/opt/gtk/bin:$PATH"
```

(Don't specify `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`; combine this into a single `CMD ["python3", "app.py"]`.  I'd encourage you to run `docker run --rm -it yourimage /bin/sh` to look around the filesystem and run debugging commands like `env`, but the `ENTRYPOINT` declaration breaks this use, and having the script file named in the `CMD` means it's still not the "container-as-command" pattern.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The main reason I used ENV PATH is to declare that I will be using the development environment. Maybe there is simpler way to declare which environment I will be using in docker?

Comment: What does "development environment" mean?  The only software that's available is what's specifically installed in the Dockerfile; a container doesn't have multiple "environments".

Comment: Well, I have a config.py file, in which I have my environment variables written for example MYSQL_HOST = os.environ['MYSQL_HOST']. When setting a specific environment, specific variables will be used, in this example, variables will be used from development.env. And if I will not declare the environment, I will receive an error as mentioned above, therefore I need to set up the environment which will be used in my dockerfile. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That's not what the `PATH` environment variable is for.  It says where to look up commands like `sh`, `ls`, `python`, and so on.  Data files or configuration are never looked up there.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood what PATH environment variable is for. So, to declare which environment I will be using I should use the command  RUN export $(grep -v '^#' ./env/development.env | xargs)? Because unfortunately, I am receiving an error mentioned above when using this command.